# Wrong height of iFrame when using Ajax in eBay listings

Tags: javascript, ajax

Using an Ajax call I load cross promotion items into my eBay listings. However, because the size of them is not known before to the eBay iFrame, it sets the height wrong and shows scrollbars, which looks very ugly.

I tried to work around this problem by creating a div at the bottom of my listing (which ends up within the eBay iFrame) that has its height set to 500px and gets it changed to 0px as soon as the ajax call has finished.

Unfortunately, this is unflexible: Different browser window width, and the loaded products will be stacked on top of each other, which means the height needs to change as well..

Is there a better way to go about that?